# Using JQuery to display one of two layouts

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use JQuery to display one of two layouts based on the width of the screen, and am running into some trouble.  The code below is an initial test to see if I can set the html to one of two different things.  I am receiving no console errors, and the code appears to have no affect.  I'm relatively new to JQuery and the little practice I've had is several months stale.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of what I am doing wrong?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> 
  <title>Main Window</title> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" /> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> 
 </head> 
 <body>
 <div id='primary'></div>
 <script>
 if (window.width > 768){
    $('primary').html('Big Window');    
 }
 else{
    $('primary').html('Small Window');
 }
 </script>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your code inside DOM ready `$(document).ready(function() { })` or `$(function() { })` and you're also missing the `#` to target element with `id` named `primary` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.width > 768){
         $('#primary').html('Big Window');    
    }
    else{
        $('#primary').html('Small Window');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

you are missing the [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (`#` in front of id) - you are using an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)(it is looking for an element like `<primary></primary`)

```
if ($(window).width() > 768){
    $('#primary').html('Big Window');   
} else {
    $('#primary').html('Small Window');   
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gH2Ze/)(increase/decrease the width of the result window and run again)

Comment: Sounds pretty spot on.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
if($(window).width()> 768)
```